# rspec API data with files upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, api, file, rspec

I want to create RSpec case for the post-API. in which data (JSON format + pdf files) are passing as form. e.g

```
        curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books' \
        --header 'Accept: application/json' \
        --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJra...' \
        --form 'book="{ \"book\":  {
                \"info\":{
                    \"reference_id\": \"43999\"
                }                                                      
        }
        }"' \
        --form 'book_content=@"/home/bookcontent.pdf"' \
        --form 'book_booksummery=@"/home/booksummery.pdf"'
```

similarly, I can also create from postman too. How can I create the same form data in rspec and attached files in params? I tried it but the controller is unable to receive params.

```
         it 'updates inquiry' do
            post '/api/v1/books', params: book="{ \"book\":  {
                \"info\":{
                    \"reference_id\": \"43999\"
                }                                                      
        }
        }".merge(book_content: fixture_file_upload('spec/fixtures/files/book_content.pdf', 'application/pdf'))
          .merge(book_booksummery: fixture_file_upload('spec/fixtures/files/book_booksummery.pdf', 'application/pdf'))
          , headers: headers_data
            
            Rails.logger.info response
            expect(response).to have_http_status(201)   # giving 422 status error code
            expect(json['reference_id']).to eq '43999'
          end
```

Comment: The post is your rspec does not have the Authorization Header info.  Do you think that is why the 422 Unprocessable Entity Error?

Comment: nope. i already provided the authorization in header. thats why it not gving 401

Comment: and I am getting in the controller like this.

 if params[:book].present?
   begin
  apiparam = JSON.parse(params[:book])
  validate_book_complete_objects(ActionController::Parameters.new(apiparam))

Comment: def validate_book_complete_objects(apiparam)
  
  apiparam[:book].require(:info)
 
  apiparam[:book_content].require(:book_content)
 
  apiparam[:book_booksummery].require(:book_booksummery)
 
 end

Answer (score 0):

The below works, picking out just key items. Basically, you can just stick to using a hash.

I am using authenticated_headers, which you may find convenient (inspiration here [here](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/issues/99#issue-343170097))

```
        @attached_file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('spec/fixtures/files/book_content.pdf')

        post "/api/v1/books",
          headers: authenticated_header(@user_1),
          params: {
            book: {
              info: '123123123',
              book_content: @attached_file
            }
          }
```

I presume your controller looks something like this

```
params.require(:book).permit(:info, :book_content)
```